# Android: How to add events intoCalendar (SPlanner,GoogleCalendar) and synchronize these events with account

Tags: java, android, synchronization

at first I will apologize for my bad English, cause I am an not native speaker. 
My issue is, I developed an application in android which crates calendar events and add this to the calendar like(S-planner, etc.) Finally this app should synchronize these events with the account.

**NOW THE PROBLEM IS THIS:**
*Creating events is no problem, but in some devices the events are not shown in the calendar. As account, gmail is used.*

**CODE:**

```
ContentResolver cr = mainActivity.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, myMonthTmp.getKurzelList().get(k));

            //Checks if the rota contains specific days like *,K, -S-, etc...
            checkIfTrickContainSpecific(values,k);

                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, user.getWorkingArea());
                values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Europe/Berlin");
            //Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            Uri uri = cr.insert(asSyncAdapter(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, user.getAccount(),user.getAccountType(user.getAccount())),values);


public Uri asSyncAdapter(Uri uri, String account, String accountType) {
    return uri.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.CALLER_IS_SYNCADAPTER, "true")
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME, account)
            .appendQueryParameter(CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
            .build();

}
```

I will very thankful for each help...